# SharePoint online page

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, pnp-js

Is there a way to get a completely blank sharepoint online page i.e. no command bar, top sharepoint branding etc.

I'm not willing to use spfx app customizer as it removes those elements after a delay.

Can powershell help here?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, I'm afraid it is impossible to get a completely blank modern page in SharePoint Online as customizing master page is not supported on modern sites.